# What is vector slice in Rust?

Tags: rust

As per [rust doc](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide.html), string slice is:

> This string is statically allocated, meaning that it's saved inside our compiled program, and exists for the entire duration it runs.

What about vector slices? Are these bytecode hardcoded values?

[Rust doc](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide.html#vectors) does not explain properly what vector slice is:

> Similar to &str, a slice is a reference to another array. We can get a slice from a vector by using the as_slice() method:

```
let vec = vec![1i, 2i, 3i];
let slice = vec.as_slice();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually... it is not *always* statically allocated. Note the specific wording:

```
let string = "Hello there.";
```

> **This** string is statically allocated, meaning that it's saved inside our compiled program, and exists for the entire duration it runs (empahsis mine).

In the case of a string literal, the string is statically allocated, and the string slice refers to it. However there are other cases of string slices where they refer to dynamically allocated strings.

---

In general, a *slice* is a contiguous sequence of elements in an array (wherever that array lives). Therefore, in Rust:

- a string slice is a slice of bytes in a UTF-8 encoded array
- a vector slice is a slice of elements (of type `T`) in an array of type `T`s

If the array has a static lifetime (ie, exists for the whole duration of the program), then this is represented with the `static` keyword:

> `&'static str` is a `&str` (string slice) with such a lifetime, it is thus the precise types of string literals in Rust.

Otherwise, the lifetime is generally bounded to that of the array owner, for example:

```
let vec = vec!(1i, 2, 3);   // create a dynamically allocated array of 3 `int`
let slice = vec.as_slice(); // create a slice into this array,
                            // the lifetime of which cannot (obviously)
                            // exceed that of the array.
```

thus if `vec` has a lifetime `'a`, then `slice` has for type `&'a [int]` as can be seen in the type signature:

```
fn as_slice(&'a self) -> &'a [T]
```

(from the [`std::vec::Vec`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_slice) page)